# Custom option price not working with bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, bundle

I am using magewrox extension for custom options.

So what is the issue?

> 1. I am trying to create bundle product.
> 2. I add bundle items.
> 3. then I try to add custom options in it with different prices.
> 4. product saves successfully.
>
> **the issue is on product detail page. while I try to select a custom option then it's price is not updating in a cart.**

Comment: product has dynamic price?

Comment: Yes there is a dynamic price

Comment: are you able create custom option? http://prntscr.com/k1jm25

Comment: Yes i already mentioned that i m using magewrox custom options extension. for it